# Angular Send Value From Service To Another Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service where I set the ID, I get this ID from another component on a click event.

```
export class MyService {

   id: number;
   constructor() {}

   public setId(value: number) {
          this.id = value;
          console.log('id:', this.id);
   }
}
```

The value gets set on this click event I have inside my menu component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['item.id]" (click)="getId(item.id);">
```

which triggers this method inside the menu component:

```
getId(datavalue: number) 
      {
            this.ms.setId(datavalue);
      }
```

How could I send that same value to another component so I can use it for display in HTML?

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit
{
   id: number;

   constructor(private ms: MyService)
    {
       this.id = ms.id;
       console.log('ms id = ', this.id);
    }
```

I've tried it like in the example above but I'm getting "undefined" in the console log.

Comment: Well where did you `setId`? Give a [mcve].

Comment: just do  ``this._ms.setId(this.id)``

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh sorry, I added where I get the value

Comment: Well if that happens *after* the component is constructed, why would you expect it to be updated? The logging should show you the order in which things happen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what would be the best way to update the value?

Comment: As linked above you have various options. Which one is "best" depends on your needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** Don't use an EventEmitter in a Service, this is just a quick Workaround!
This post covers all your needs: [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular/35568924#35568924)

<strike>You could use an **EventEmitter** in your Service:</strike>

```
  id: number;
  idUpdated = new EventEmitter();

  setId(value: number) 
  {
         this.id = value;
         this.idUpdated.emit(this.id);
         console.log('id:', this.id);
  }

  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
```

And then **subscribe** to the changes of the property in your detail component:

```
id: number;
ngOnInit()
   {
    this.ms.idUpdated.subscribe(
        (id) => {
          this.id = this.ms.getId();
          console.log(this.id);
        }
      );
   }
```

Comment: Per [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) EventEmitter is for use *"by directives and components"*. When writing services you should use regular Subjects and Observables. Also it's unwise to expose the emitter/subject as public; that allows values to be pushed into the stream from outside the service. I wrote a bit about this pattern: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe I stand corrected. Edited my answer and will update the code as soon as possible.